# Firebase throws ERROR FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native

Here is my `FirebaseSetup.js` File

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "MyApi",
    authDomain: "MyAuthDomain",
    databaseURL: "DBurl",
    projectId: "PID",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...."
}

if(!firebase.app.length){                   //The Problem
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); //arises in
    console.log('FireBase Initialized');    //these lines
}

console.log(`FIREBASE INSTANCES : => ${firebase.app.length}`);

export default () => {
    return {firebase,auth}
}
```

when I comment the above mentioned lines the app works fine but is not connected to my firebaseDB

When I uncomment the above mentioned line it Throws ERROR that says.....

`FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists!`
besides the FIREBASE INSTANCES shows `0` as length..

Atlast i Understood that myself can't able to initialize App.. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the firebase apps length in this way:

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
```

Note that the property is in plural, `apps` and not `app`.

More information cand by found here:

https://rnfirebase.io/reference/app

Note that both `app` and `apps` are valid properties but you actually need the `apps` one, since what you are checking for is the length of array of `apps`.